# How to change multiple row values of a column in a dataframe based on a condition?

Tags: r

How can I do the following in an efficient way?

Thanks in advance

```
data[data$id==108452,]$amount = 0.000000000000000000001
data[data$id==132649,]$amount = 0.000000000000000000001
data[data$id==476849,]$amount = 0.000000000000000000001
data[data$id==477624,]$amount = 0.000000000000000000001
data[data$id==584641,]$amount = 0.000000000000000000001
data[data$id==729446,]$amount = 0.000000000000000000001
data[data$id==773057,]$amount = 0.000000000000000000001
data[data$id==793200,]$amount = 0.000000000000000000001
data[data$id==796237,]$amount = 0.000000000000000000001
data[data$id==955267,]$amount = 0.000000000000000000001
data[data$id==973793,]$amount = 0.000000000000000000001
data[data$id==976742,]$amount = 0.000000000000000000001
data[data$id==1028635,]$amount = 0.000000000000000000001
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `%in%`:

```r
data$amount[data$id %in% c(108452, 132649, 476849,
  477624, 584641, 729446,
  773057, 793200, 796237,
  955267, 973793, 976742,
  1028635)] <- 0.000000000000000000001
```

Comment: Thanks! What if I want to let the computer check the zero values of the column and after that do the replacement? I tried this: ```data$amount[data$id %in% which(data$amount <= 0)] <- 0.000000000000000000001``` but it didn't work. However ```which(data$amount <= 0)``` returns the same vector as ```c(108452, 132649, 476849,
  477624, 584641, 729446,
  773057, 793200, 796237,
  955267, 973793, 976742,
  1028635)```

Comment: You can simplify the call by `data$amount[data$amount <= 0] <- 0`